# Using Firebase JS SDK offline capability vs promises to cache data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, firebase, offline-caching

We are trying to design an web app that needs to be frugal with consuming network. And we are using Firebase.

Firebase JS SDK claims it has offline capability, but this example uses promises to cache user data. 
http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/jgay49r0/embedded/result,js/

It seems offline capability makes this promises based UsersCache redundant.

```
function UsersCache( refToUsersPath ) {
   this.ref = refToUsersPath;
   this.userPromises = {};
}

UsersCache.prototype.getUser = function(userId) {
   if( !this.userPromises.hasOwnProperty(userId) ) {
      this.userPromises[userId] = this._monitor(userId);
   }
   return this.userPromises[userId];
};

UsersCache.prototype._monitor = function(userId) {
   var def = $.Deferred();
   this.ref.child(userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
      def.resolve(snapshot.val());
   });        
   return def.promise();
};
```

Can someone comment and help us choose the best path?

Comment: Firebase's JavaScript SDK handles *intermittent connectivity loss*. So if your network drops for a minute and then reconnects, the app will remain working. But if the user reloads the page, the cache will be cleared. So the app will not have access to previously seen data and any pending writes will be lost.

Comment: If you are using AngularJS, you should be using the [AngularFire API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) which uses promises from the AngularJS `$q` service. Avoid jQuery promises when using AngularJS.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - In that case promises based implementation as shown in the above jsfillde also wont work, right?

Comment: @georgeawg - Thanks for reminding.